# Powershell export-csv shows System.Object[],"System.Object[]"

Tags: json, powershell, export-to-csv, export-csv, foreach-object

I want to export my powershell script to csv, only when the file is exported, I get the headers in my csv file, but the data contains systemobject.

```
#------- Opvragen token tiptrack -------
#Dit is de URL waar de token voor tiptrack wordt opgevraagd.
$Url_token="https://tiptracknext-staging-login.indicia.nl/oauth2/aus342go9hNphcHXM0i7/v1/token"

#Dit is de body die mee wordt gestuurd in de request, deze informatie staat gelijk aan de data in de post request vanuit de handleiding.
$Data_token = @{
grant_type="client_credentials"
client_id="123457"
client_secret="123456"
scope="eapi"
}

$token_tiptrack=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Url_token -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $Data_token

#------- Opvragen Employerbudgetsid -------
#Dti is de URL waarna de GET request wordt gestuurd om het employerid te kunnen.
$Url_budgetid='https://staging.tiptrack.nl/Tiptrack.Employer.Api/odata/EmployeeBudgets?$expand=Employee($expand=SecureEmployee)&$top=5'

#Dit is header die mee wordt gestuurd in de request. Deze data in deze header staat gelijk aan de data in de API handleiding.
$header_process = @{
Authorization='Bearer '+$token_tiptrack.access_token
"accept"="application/json"
}

#Vanuit het uploaden van het bestand krijgen we een reactie van de server, in deze reactie staat het upload id, deze id hebben we nodig om het bestand te kunnen verwerken. 
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url_budgetid -Method Get -Headers $header_process 


$exportdata = $data | 
    ForEach-Object { return [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        EmployeeNumber = $_.Value.Employee.SecureEmployee.EmployeeNumber;
        ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount =($_.Value.ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount) ;
        }  } 

$exportdata  | Select EmployeeNumber,ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount | Export-Csv C:\afas\test3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the ouput that i want:

```
# EmployeeNumber,ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount
# EMP1,100,00
# EMP2,250,49
# EMP3,450,00
```

Comment: Try to omitt the `return` in the `ForEach-Object` or `return` the whole `exportdata`. Next try this and inspect the `$ExportCsv`-Object: `$ExportCsv = 
$exportdata  | Select EmployeeNumber,ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount `  What does `$ExportCsv.getType()` say?

Comment: is the get returning json?

Comment: This is the output:
EmployeeNumber                                  ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount          
--------------                                  ----------------------------          
{A20200626-00, A20200626-01, 100003, 100015...} {$null, $null, 1695,4000, 323,0400...}

Comment: @T-Me, this is the reaction when i do $ExportCsv.getType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

Comment: You have multiple arrays at different depths on your data. Is there another deeper level where data sets share the same array? Maybe you need `$data | foreach-object { $_.Value | Foreach-Object { $_.Employee.SecureEmployee.EmployeeNumber } }`. Without seeing the returned data from the `GET`, it'll be difficult to guess.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, https://pastebin.com/SmdMxFpX i made an pastebin where de raw data stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided output data does not list any data for the `SecureEmployee` property. So I'll assume your property hierarchy in your code is correct. The `Value` property contains an array of Employee objects that you will need to iterate.

```
$exportdata = $data.Value | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        EmployeeNumber = $_.Employee.SecureEmployee.EmployeeNumber
        ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount = $_.ComputedCurrentBalanceAmount
    }
} 

$exportdata | Export-Csv C:\afas\test3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```